# How to create a vector dataset from mesh data for QGIS

Tags: qgis, grib, mesh

QGIS can read time-varying GRIB files as a "mesh" data source, which is neat. The [dataset](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_mesh/mesh_properties.html#datasets) is documented to be either a scalar or vector dataset. I'm able to open my GRIB files as scalar without any issues, but I'm unable to open it as a vector dataset (e.g. as [demonstrated in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgVBP2jxF14)). Here is the Layer Properties for a single GRIB file with two groups that represent magnitude along [East/West](https://codes.ecmwf.int/grib/param-db/?id=180) and [North/South](https://codes.ecmwf.int/grib/param-db/?id=181) directions:

[image]

How can I open the mesh data that combines the two as a vector dataset to see "surface stress" data? Can this be done in QGIS, or does the GRIB data need pre-processing to be interpreted as a vector dataset?